# travis-CI.org project cannot submit code coverage report to Coveralls.io

Tags: maven, travis-ci, coveralls

I have a maven project which uses Travis-CI for continuous integration, and I want to add code coverage using JaCoCo, and Coveralls.io.

The build in Travis-CI runs fine, and the code coverage results are generated properly (at least, according to the log). But the result submission fails with a 422, like so:

```
[INFO] Starting Coveralls job for travis-ci (188355098)
[INFO] Using repository token <secret>
...
[INFO] Writing Coveralls data to /home/travis/build/bThink-BGU/BPjs/target/coveralls.json...
[INFO] Processing coverage report from /home/travis/build/bThink-BGU/BPjs/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
[INFO] Successfully wrote Coveralls data in 224ms
[INFO] Gathered code coverage metrics for 43 source files with 2944 lines of code:
[INFO] - 902 relevant lines
...
[INFO] Submitting Coveralls data to API
[ERROR] Submission failed in 442ms while processing data
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eluder.coveralls:coveralls-maven-plugin:4.3.0:report (default-cli) on project BPjs: Processing of input or output data failed: Report submission to Coveralls API failed with HTTP status 422: Unprocessable Entity (Couldn't find a repository matching this job.) -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what's wrong? I've tried to explicitly add the `TRAVIS_JOB_ID`, as suggested in [Maven coveralls plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120891/maven-coveralls-plugin), but for no avail.

The [repo](https://github.com/bThink-BGU/BPjs/tree/develop) is open, so as far as I could tell I do not need a repo token.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the very same problem.  Have you resolved your problem yet?  `Failed to execute goal org.eluder.coveralls:coveralls-maven-plugin:4.3.0:report (default-cli) on project http-server: Processing of input or output data failed: Report submission to Coveralls API failed with HTTP status 422: Unprocessable Entity (Couldn't find a repository matching this job.) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: This ended up being an error in my Pom file. Make sure you follow coverall's instructions exactly.

Comment: I am so embarrassed.  You were right.  For some reason my copy and paste included that stubbed in `<repoToken>yourcoverallsprojectrepositorytoken</repoToken>` business.  It's so simple and obvious I looked right over it.